# Extern const, which is the declaration and which is the forward declaration

Tags: c++, constants, extern, linkage

Let's say I have the following setup in a C++ program, in global/namespace scope (outside of any block):

Situation 1:

a.cpp

```
extern const int i=5;
```

b.cpp

```
extern const int i;
```

There are two ways, in my mind, that the compiler could see this.  One is that the true declaration of i is in b.cpp, while a.cpp has merely a forward declaration and the initialization. (Since we know that for specifically extern consts, initialization at the time of declaration is not required)  The other possible executable the compiler could generate would have a.cpp containing the true declaration, with initialization, and the statement in b.cpp is seen as a forward declaration, merely required to be there to assist the compiler in knowing what i is.

How does the compiler decide which file is responsible for the actual declaration, and therefore memory allocation associated with i?  This could have outwardly observable effects if, instead of int, a type with an interesting constructor were used.

How does the answer to this question change, if at all, with:

situation 2:

a.cpp

```
extern const int i;
extern const int i=5;
```

b.cpp

```
extern const int i;
```

Comment: You're declaring it `extern` and you're also saying you know the value of it. That seems wrong.

Comment: @tadman There aren't any errors when I compile.  Why is this wrong?  I thought "extern" just means that the identifier name has external linkage.  Does it also mean that you can't initialize it to a known value?

Comment: Usually `extern` means "stored in another file" and the linker takes care of making it sync up. How are you compiling all of this?

Comment: @tadman for simplicity we can assume that I have a main function somewhere that prints i, and that's it.

Comment: The way I've always done it is to declare `extern` and uninitialized in a shared header (`.h`) file, then initialize that in one and only one implementation (`.cpp`) file.

Comment: @tadman: `extern` does not necessarily mean "stored in another file". `extern` means "has external linkage". When `extern` is applied to a *definition* is has "export" semantics (i.e. "is accessible to other files"). When `extern` is apllied to a *non-defining declaration* is has "import" semantics (i.e. "stored in another file").

Comment: @AnT That's a much better definition of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presence of an initializer immediately turns a declaration into a *definition* (with few exceptions, irrelevant in our context). Which means that

```
extern const int i = 5;
```

is a *definition* of your `i`. It defines `i` and gives it external linkage, i.e. creates the actual `i` and makes it visible to other translation units ("exports" it).

Meanwhile,

```
extern const int i;
```

is a non-defining declaration if `i`. It basically says that `i` is defined elsewhere ("imports" it).

When you for some reason need a global `const` object in C++, the proper explicit application of `extern` becomes crucial, since in C++ `const` objects have *internal linkage* by default.

Just keep in mind that in order for a `const int` object to be eligible for Integral Constant Expressions (ICE), a declaration of that `const int` object with an ICE initializer has to be visible.

Comment: what happens in situation 2 when both files have an extern const int statement, and neither one is attached to an initialization, which occurs afterward in a.cpp?

Comment: @Jeff: Nothing special. You have multiple non-defining declarations for `i` (which is prefectly fine, you can have unlimited number of those) and a single definition of `i` (you can have no more than one). So, everythig is in order. The linker will properly link everything together.

Comment: It sounds like you're saying that in situation 2, the "extern const int i=5;" is defining. But what I'm confused about is which of the 3 statements in situation 2 is responsible for the memory allocation for i. I.e. when does i first come into existence? Another way to ask this is, of the two extern const int i; statements in a.cpp and b.cpp, one is a real declaration, and the other is a heads-up to the compiler on what type of data i represents. Which is which? Thanks!

Comment: @Jeff: The *definition* of `i` is exactly that: it is memory allocation for `i`. `extern const int i;` is just a "heads-up" for the compiler. `extern const int i = 5;` is the actual memory allocation for `i`.

Comment: it sounds like you are telling me that among non-defining declarations, all of them are always forward declarations, and not one of them is special.  Memory is only allocated upon definition.  So even though compilers often give you garbage when you ask for uninitialized values, this doesn't actually mean the memory is supposed to be allocated already.  It's just a compiler-writer's choice on what happens during undefined behavior.

Comment: Moreover, if int is replaced by a class type, constructors won't be called by extern const classtype x;?  How does it tell if I wanted to forward declare x, or if I wanted to construct x with a no-argument constructor?  Btw, it seems like in this and the previous comment, the use of extern doesn't actually matter.  Is that correct?  My real misunderstanding seems like it was about when the object is created, even within just one .cpp file.

Comment: @Jeff: Exactly. "Non-defining declaration" is exactly what is also called "just a declaration" or "forward declaration". All of `extern const int i;` are just forward declarations. None of them are special. However, I'm not sure what you mean when you talk about uninitialized values.

Comment: And yes `extern const classtype x;` does not "call constructors". It is "just a forward declaration" of `x`. What constructor gets called is determined by the *definition* of `x`, which will include an initailizer: e.g. `extern const classtype x{};` is a default-constructed definition. Or `extern const classtype x(1, 2, 3);` is a definition initialized by some three-parameter constructor. You will have one and only one definition among all of your `.cpp` files. And that definition will determine how the object is created and which constructor is used.

Comment: Use of `extern` is usually optional (redundant) in object *definitions*. However, for global definitions of `const` objects it is absolutely necessary. Without `extern` a `const` object would have internal linkage, i.e. it woudn't be global.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134228/discussion-between-jeff-and-ant).